# These were the problems I remember having at home

Tags: grammar, relative-clauses

> These were the problems I remember having at home

Hi, this sentence is right? My reasoning is as follows.

> These were the problems.
>
> ＋
>
> I remember having the problems at home.

So, two sentences are combined by relative clause.

⇒ These were the problems (that) I remember having at home.

Right?

Comment: The sentence is fine. As you note **that** is optional.

Comment: Yes: a variable representation is: "These were the problems _x_; I remember having _x_ at home". Note that a _wh_ relative is also possible.